# My CSS code seems to inherit first option

Tags: html, css

For some reason, the padding in my #login fieldset does not apply. Any idea why?

**login.html**

```
<div id="login">

  <fieldset>

    <p>Line 1 <input type=""></p>

    <p>Line 2 <input type=""></p>

  </fieldset>

</div>
```

**style.css**

```
fieldset, h2, p {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#login fieldset {
  padding: 20px 20px;
}
```

My code seems to take the margin:0 and padding:0. I need Line 1 and Line 2 to have padding between.

Comment: Seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2SMZ7/. If your `<p>` elements need more margin, them remove the selector from your rule.

Comment: it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/d57S2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `p` to have no margin... Either remove it from your current CSS or add margin like so

```
p {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Or as I said remove `p` from your current CSS

```
fieldset, h2 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably be better to add the margin.

Comment: Yeah that's what I would do, just though I'd better show where the lack of margin had come from.

Comment: Removing p helped! I did however forgot to mention I had #login fieldset p with padding set.